# I've run into a php class semantics conundrum

Tags: php, class, semantics

I have two classes, one of them is a configuration class. Inside of this class I have a variable called "theme". This is called config::theme . I have another class, but I can't be sure on the name as It's theme dependant. For instance, if the PHP sites theme is set to "nebula", I need to access the nebula theme, e.g: nebula::navigation . The farthest I've gotten is:

```
public static function nav( ) {
    $temp = config::theme;

    return eval( $temp . "::navigation" );
}
```

which outputs the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   $end in
>   C:\Dropbox\Colzdragon\Colzdragon\Site\internal\theme.php(54)
>   : eval()'d code on line 1

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I find this always helps http://www.classnamer.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using PHP 5.3. See the first example on [this manual page](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

```
public static function nav() {
    $theme = config::$theme;
    return $theme::$navigation;
}
```

Comment: @egis: No, unfortunately for you not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine (as far as I can tell) PHP is telling you that you missed a `}`, a `;` or a quote somewhere.

Literally it says: "I've read until the end of the file but there is unfinished syntactical business"

Answer (score 0):

[@Sander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576829/ive-run-into-a-php-class-semantics-conundrum/5576855#5576855) works if you have access to PHP 5.3. If you're stuck using an older version (since a lot of cheap hosts don't seem to have 5.3 yet), you can use `constant()` for this:

```
constant(get_class($temp)."::navigation");
```